# Matlab: Finding index of first char occurrence in Cell Array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array of dates in MATLAB as such:

```
dates = {'10/2/2010' ; '9/1/2011'}
```

and I would like to extract the months only so that it returns

```
months = 
'10'
'9'
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
cellfun(@(x) x(1:(strfind(x,'/')(1)-1)), dates, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

It says "Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index
expression." Basically I have the (1) indexing there to get the index of the first occurrence of '/', and then I subtract 1 from it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small modification will make your code work.

```
cellfun(@(x) x(1:(strfind(x(1:3),'/')-1)), dates, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The hard-coded `1:3` should work even if you write the same date in 4 different styles.

```
1. 09/01/2011     2. 9/01/2011
3. 9/1/2011       4. 09/1/2011
```

The key here is to not encounter the second `/` sign.

Comment: Here's another one-liner: `cellfun(@(x) x, regexp(dates, '^\d+', 'match'))`, though I find Divakar's approaches more elegant as the intent is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1** Using [`datevec`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) -

```
%// Input
dates = {'10/2/2010' ; '9/1/2011'}

%// Convert date and time to vector of components
datevec_out = datevec(dates)

%// Extract the month information only contained in the second column
out = cellstr(num2str(datevec_out(:,2)))
```

Code run -

```
dates = 
    '10/2/2010'
    '9/1/2011'
datevec_out =
        2010          10           2           0           0           0
        2011           9           1           0           0           0
out = 
    '10'
    ' 9'
```

---

**Approach #2** By splitting into cells with `regexp(..'Split')`

```
%// Input
dates = {'10/2/2010' ; '9/1/2011'}

%// Split into cells using `/` as the "separator"
dates_split = regexp(dates,'/','Split')

%// Vertically concatenate all cells into a single cell array
%// to reduce "cell-nesting"
dates_split_catcell = vertcat(dates_split{:})

%// Extract the month information only contained in the first column
out = dates_split_catcell(:,1)
```

Code run -

```
dates = 
    '10/2/2010'
    '9/1/2011'
dates_split = 
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
dates_split_catcell = 
    '10'    '2'    '2010'
    '9'     '1'    '2011'
out = 
    '10'
    '9'
```